# Spark Dataset map row 'cannot resolve method map(<lambda expression>)'

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

Trying to create RDD out of Dataset by trying to map to each row in the Dataset. Getting `cannot resolve method map(<lambda expression>)` error on the `map` in `df1.map(r ->`:

```
Dataset<Object> df1 = session.read().parquet(tableName).as(Encoders.bean(Object.class));

JavaRDD<List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>> tempDatas1 = df1.map(r -> new MapFunction<Object, List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>>(){
            //@Override
            public List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>> call(Object row) throws Exception
            {

            // Get the sample property, remove leading and ending spaces and split it by comma
            // to get each sample individually
            List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> samples = zipWithIndex((row.getSamples().trim().split(",")));

            // Gets the unique identifier for that s.
            Long snp = row.getPos();

            // Calculates the hamming distance.
            return samples.stream().map(t -> {
                String alleles = t._1();
                Integer patient = t._2();

                List<String> values = Arrays.asList(alleles.split("\\|"));

                Double firstAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(0));
                Double secondAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(1));

                // Returns the initial s id, p id and the distance in form of Tuple.
                return new Tuple3<>(snp, patient, firstAllele + secondAllele);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `map` takes an `Encoder`.  You didn't provide one.

Comment: @user9613318 do you have any pointers on how to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the word count example - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/de14d35f77071932963a994fac5aec0e5df838a1/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/JavaStructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.java#L94